# Can't initialize custom form objects on second datatables pages

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

You can add static form object's like selects & inputs to datatable columns as shown here:
https://datatables.net/examples/api/form.html

But I'm trying to add custom bootstrap widgets.  Like TouchSpin found here:
http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-touchspin/

When I initialize TouchSpin it only initializes the objects on the first datatables page shown, the objects on the second/third pages are not initialized.

Anyone have an idea how to fix this?  Its probably because the second/third pages are not part of the DOM yet?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to hook into is the "drawCallback" function.  You can specify it in the options when creating the DataTable.  It would look something like this:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  //... Your other options ... //
  drawCallback: function(settings) {
      // This callback is called when the draw is complete which happens on:  
      // paging, sorting, and of course when you call ".draw()".  The current
      // DataTable page is in the DOM with all the HTML.

      // You can get the jquery element for the table like this.
      var dataTableJqueryObj = $(this);

      // You can get the API object like this.
      var apiDataTableObj = this.api();

      // Initialize your controls ...        
  }
});
```

Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try.